# populating list at size with pthreads popping off list

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a singly-linked list containing 1 value in each element.

```
struct listElement
{
    char guid[20];
    struct listElement *next;
    struct listElement *last;
    int numElements;
};
```

The code launches 10 pthreads in a pool that are all `pthread_cond_wait()` for an element to get added to the list.

My main() is reading strings from a file, one line at a time and populating the linked list by calling `listPush(val)`

`listPush(val)` acquires lock, creates new element, adds to end of list (or creates head if empty) unlocks then calls `pthread_cond_signal()` to let one of the 10 threads know there is now an element with work to be done.

In the case where numElements > numThreads I call `pthread_cond_broadcast()` because there should be enough work for each thread to pop and go.

Each thread `listPop(rVal)`'s off a value (locks, removes, fixes pointers, unlocks) and processes it, then goes back to `pthread_cond_wait()` state.

My file has around 200 million lines. (1.2GB)  I don't want my linked list to get this large so I am trying to "throttle" the size of linked list.

Inside `listPush()`, before I lock the mutex, I have

```
if(head && head->numElements >= maxNumElements)
{
    while(head && head->numElements >= maxNumElements)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The idea is that if I "fill up" my list, I wait for the threads to process a chunk of it before adding more. I've reached this point where the app starts "pulsing"; basically I can see it waiting 1 second. I would expect this to never happen or happen very infrequently.

Is there a better way to limit the size of my list other than using `sleep()`?

Comment: *unlocks then calls pthread_cond_signal()* -- The signaling is usually done inside the critical section, ie before the unlock.

Comment: Each consumer thread should also signal the next consumner if the list is still non-empty after the pop.

Comment: @chrisaycock: that may be how it's often done, but there's no requirement for that.  In fact, it probably reduces contention for the mutex somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a classic [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). The solution is to have `listPush()` wait on a condition variable if the list is too big. Then one of the consumer threads can signal this condition variable once a list element has been consumed.

A completely different approach is to just use a `pipe()` to handle both the communication and the synchronization. That will obviate the need for both the linked list and the mutex.

Comment: After reading man pages, `pipe()` appears to be just what I am looking for. Never knew about it. Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rather than using sleep you can wait on a semaphore (similar to a mutex but in the other way) and be awaken when a new element is added to the list. You might be able to find a *event* library or do it yourself with pthreads.